# Spring Context Initialization fails

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I'm pretty much stucked and I hope you guys can help me out. Somehow I can't manage to get my spring context initialized.

I have these nice Bean Configuration classes:

```
@Configuration
public class CoreConfig {

    @Bean
    public TeamService createService(TeamPersistenceService teamPersistenceService) {
    return new TeamEventHandler(teamPersistenceService);
    }
}
```

And this one:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "de.ktv.persistence.repository", //
includeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(value = { TeamsRepository.class }, type =                            FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE))
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class PersistenceConfig {

    @Bean
    public TeamPersistenceService createService(TeamsRepository repository) {
    return new TeamPersistenceEventHandler(repository);
    }
}
```

And in this test I want to use them:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { CoreConfig.class, PersistenceConfig.class })
public class CoreIntegrationTest {

@Autowired
TeamService teamService;

@Test
public void addNewTeamToTheSystem() {

    //some test

}
```

The PersistenceConfig.class I am using in a different test and it works fine. But somehow here combined with CoreConfig.class it fails to initialize.

That is the error I get:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [de.ktv.core.services.TeamService] found for
>   dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

I would really appreciate any help/hint.Thanks!

Comment: The problem is in testing?

Comment: Eventually yes, since the UnitUnderTest(TeamService.class) doesn't get initalized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SpringContext cannot bind the @autowired if you don't indicate the same name. By default, the bean name will be the same as the method name, in this case, he is different, 2 options : change the method name or add attribut name !

Option 1

```
@Bean(name = "teamService")
public TeamService createService(TeamsRepository repository) {
return new TeamPersistenceEventHandler(repository);
}
```

Option 2

```
@Bean
public TeamService teamService(TeamsRepository repository) {
return new TeamPersistenceEventHandler(repository);
}
```

Enjoy \o/

Comment: Can you explain why it helps?

Comment: SpringContext cannot bind the @autowired if you don't indicate the same name. By default, the bean name will be the same as the method name, in this case, he is different, 2 options : change the method name or add attribut name

Comment: I always thought that autowire use type, not name

Answer (score 1):

```
@Configuration
public class CoreConfig {
    @Autowired
    private TeamPersistenceService teamPersistenceService;

    @Bean
    public TeamService teamService() {
    return new TeamEventHandler(teamPersistenceService);
    }
}
```

And this one:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "de.ktv.persistence.repository", //
includeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(value = { TeamsRepository.class }, type =                            FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE))
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class PersistenceConfig {
    @Autowired
    private TeamsRepository repository:

    @Bean
    public TeamPersistenceService teamPersistenceService() {
    return new TeamPersistenceEventHandler(repository);
    }
}
```

And in this test I want to use them:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { CoreConfig.class, PersistenceConfig.class })
public class CoreIntegrationTest {

@Autowired
TeamService teamService;

@Test
public void addNewTeamToTheSystem() {

    //some test

}
```